# Can we expand and collapse expansion tile programatically in flutter?

Tags: flutter, performance, dart, flutter-layout, logic

I want to know, **is this possible to expand and collapse the ExpansionTile programmatically**?

If yes, Is this possible to use the key just like we do in **drawer**? But I already tried like this but maybe I'm doing something wrong for sure.

Comment: By programmatically does it mean by clicking on widget or without clicking it should expand and collapse?

Comment: yes, exactly. But i did it by creating custom expansion tile widget.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code of ExpansionTile widget, it doesn't look like you can programatically change it's state it doesn't accept an outside controller. You could create a widget and take a controller as a parameter and then use the controller to change the state.

If you need any help building that, let me know, would love to help you out.

Comment: no, it's not working like that.